# Adjust / norm python dictionary values to certain size / length

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question regarding how to limit the value length of a dictionary:

```
real_vertrices_copy = {
     'key': {1,3,8,4,2},
     'key1': {9,4,2,4},
     'key2': {6,4,2},
     'key3': {9,3,5,3,5}
    }
```

The dictionary consists of key value pairs, with the values varying in length.
I want to limit the length of the values to 3, so if the length of the values is > 3, I want to pop random elements as many times necessary to reduce it to len=3.

I tried it like this:

```
for x in real_vertrices_copy.values():
if len(x) > 20:
    real_vertrices_copy.popitem()
```

but this just removes random dictionary entries (I did not expect this to work, I have to admit)

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thank you and BR

Comment: Are you aware that `{9,3,5,3,5}` is `{9,3,5}`? or did you incorrectly use a set?

Comment: Could your data have values with a length less than 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with random sampling ([`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)):

```
d = {'key': {1,3,8,4,2},
     'key1': {9,4,2,4},
     'key2': {6,4,2},
     'key3': {9,3,5,3,5}
    }

import random
out = {k: set(random.sample(list(v), 3)) for k,v in d.items()}
```

or, if it is possible that the input has less than 3 elements:

```
N = 3
out = {k: set(random.sample(list(v), N)) if len(v)>=N else v
       for k,v in d.items()}
```

example output:

```
{'key': {1, 3, 8}, 'key1': {2, 4, 9}, 'key2': {2, 4, 6}, 'key3': {3, 5, 9}}
```

###### classical loop

If you need a classical loop and want to get both kept and discarded items, take advantage of set operations:

```
N = 3
keep = {}
discard = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    keep[k] = set(random.sample(list(v), min(len(v), N)))
    discard[k] = v.difference(keep[k])
    
print(keep)
# {'key': {1, 2, 4}, 'key1': {9, 2, 4}, 'key2': {2, 4, 6}, 'key3': {9, 3, 5}}
print(discard)
# {'key': {8, 3}, 'key1': set(), 'key2': set(), 'key3': set()}
```

Comment: sampling from a set is deprecated as of 3.9

Comment: @Stuart thanks for the comment, I had forgotten that (I tested on 3.8)! I updated ;)

Comment: Crashes if a set has less than 3 elements -> `random.sample(v, min(len(v), 3))` or explicit length checking

Comment: @timgeb good point! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just pop three times from each set with more than three elements to get three arbitrary elements:

```
d = {
    'key': {1,3,8,4,2},
    'key1': {9,4,2,4},
    'key2': {6,4,2},
    'key3': {9,3,5,3,5}
}
d = {
    k: {v.pop() for _ in range(3)} if len(v) > 3 else v
    for k, v in d.items()
}
```

This assumes that there are no other references to the sets in `d` because the mutation via `pop` will be seen across all references.

Answer (score 0):

Inplace update of real_vertrices_copy:

```
import random

real_vertrices_copy = {'key': {1,3,8,4,2},
     'key1': {9,4,2,4},
     'key2': {6,4,2},
     'key3': {9,3,5,3,5}
    }
for k, v in real_vertrices_copy.items():
    while len(v) > 3:
        v.remove(random.choice(tuple(v)))
```